# Error: "Improper operand type"

Tags: assembly, x86-16

This is a 8086 assembly program to convert 8-bit decimal number to hex number.
On the 14th line, why do I get next error?

> improper operand type

```
.model small
.data
d1 DB 81d
d1 DB 16d
res DB ?
.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
xor ax,ax
xor bx,bx
mov al,d1
mov bl,d2
div bl
ror ah,4   ;Error occurs here
add ah,al
mov ax,res
int 3h
align 16
End
```

Comment: Which line is the 14th line - can you add '    <--line14' onto that line, please.

Comment: Why do you have a space between . and data?

Comment: @ tony M it is the "ROR ah,4" instruction

Comment: @brhans Sorry,It was a typing error.

Comment: Does it work if you replace ror ah,4 with four lines of ror ah,1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ROR` (and `ROL`/`SHL`/`SHR`/etc) with an immediate operand greater than 1 has been available starting from the 80186 processor only. It is unavailable on the 8086/88. The alternative is to do a sequence of 4 *`ROR ah, 1`*, or to use *`ROR ah, cl`* after having set `CL` to 4.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Added_with_80186.2F80188